# Convert objects inside one array, into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do i convert

```
const peopleArray = [
  { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
  { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 },
  { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23 },
  { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23 },
  { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23 }
]
```

to

```
const peopleArray = [[{ id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 }],
      [{ id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 }],
      [{ id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23 }],
      [{ id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23 }],
      [{ id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23 }]]
```

I appreciate any help. Is there an ES6 method i could use. Do not want to use lodash or any other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and wrap each value in an array literal:

```js
const peopleArray = [
  { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
  { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 },
  { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23 },
  { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23 },
  { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23 }
];

console.log(peopleArray.map(person => [person]));
```